# Default value for struct member in c++

Tags: c++11, struct

It seems that we can not give a default value for struct members in c++,but I find that code as below can compile and run, why? Am I missing something?

```
struct Type {
    int i = 0xffff;
};
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Type {
    int i = 0xffff;
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Type val;
    std::cout << val.i << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does your compiler support c++11 standard??.

Comment: This type of initialisation was added to c++11. This means we can initialise in one place instead of in every constructor.

Comment: @tmp Yes, please click the hyper link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to depend on the compiler you use.

For gcc and clang you need to pass the flag `-std=c++11` to the compiler.

Support for member initializer and other c++11 features:

- gcc since 4.7. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).
- clang since 3.0. See [here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).
- Visual studio compiler in its 2013 version. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and introduced in C++11 standard. This concept is known as `in-class member initializer`

You can check Stroustrup  FAQ link on this concept:

http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init